# How can i set all checkboxes by default to be unchecked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added a new form with some checkboxes.
By default when the settings.txt file is created, nothing is written to it. So I'm getting some errors since the variable values contain only one item/index so the line

```
checkBox2.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));
```

will give out of bound index exception, and also the line

```
checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]));
```

What I want to do is if the settings.txt file is empty, set all checkboxes to false (unchecked) and also to write to the settings.txt file the values of each checkbox as false/unchecked.

The problem is, I'm writing to the file the values only in the event.

I need to manage it also in the constructor public OptionsMenuForm()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class OptionsMenuForm : Form
    {
        string settingsFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath)
            + "\\settings" + "\\settings.txt";


        public OptionsMenuForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] values = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(settingsFile).Split(',');
            checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]));
            if (Form1.files.Length == 0)
            {
                checkBox2.Checked = false;
                checkBox2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox2.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));
            }
            checkBox3.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[2]));
            checkBox4.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[3]));

            checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxesCheckedChanged;
            checkBox2.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxesCheckedChanged;
            checkBox3.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxesCheckedChanged;
            checkBox4.CheckedChanged += CheckBoxesCheckedChanged;
        }

        private void CheckBoxesCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sbValues = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;

            i = checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
            sbValues.Append(i.ToString() + ",");

            i = checkBox2.Checked ? 1 : 0;
            sbValues.Append(i.ToString() + ",");

            i = checkBox3.Checked ? 1 : 0;
            sbValues.Append(i.ToString() + ",");

            i = checkBox4.Checked ? 1 : 0;
            sbValues.Append(i.ToString() + ",");

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(settingsFile, sbValues.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (values.Length == 0)`

Comment: `foreach(var cb in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
  //do stuff set your your controls .Checked Property to false.
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
var settings =  System.IO.File.ReadAllText(settingsFile);
if(settings =="")
{
    settings = "0,0,0,0,0";
}

string[] values = settings.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way:

```
this.checkBox1.Checked = false;
this.checkBox2.Checked = false;
this.checkBox3.Checked = false;
this.checkBox4.Checked = false;
```

The more difficult way:

```
foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctl is CheckBox) (ctl as CheckBox).Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood your settingsFile looks something like this:

> "a,b,c,d,e"

(a-e being the indivudal settings).
I would first check if the string isn't empty

```
string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(settingsFile);
if (allText.Length == 0)
{
    // Set all checkBoxes to be unchecked
}
else
{
    string[] values = allTextSplit(',');
    // ......
}
```

That way the references to your string-array would never be executed, since you check for the Length of the settings before, and therefore not causing the OutOfRange Exception.

Alternatively, what I would prefer:

```
string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(settingsFile);
if (allText.Split(',').Length != 5)
{ // ... }
```

That way you check for the amount of values you get from the settings File.